# Self teaching professional java skills

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, gwt

I've been programming in java for a while and I really like the language, I've mostly just done game programming, but I want to get a feel for some of the more commonly used api's and frameworks and just get a generally more well-rounded grasp of the language and the common libraries in the current job market.

From what I found things like spring, hibernate, and GWT are pretty in demand right now. I looked at some tutorials online and they weren't hard to follow but I really felt like I had no context for what I was learning - I had no idea how any of it would be use in a real work environment. I know nothing can rival the benefit I'd get from actual work experience but that's not an option for me right now, I need another way to learn these technologies in a way where I'll at least feel comfortable working with them and know what I'm doing beyond just understanding what code does what. I checked out a few books but they were all really old(like pre-2006, am I right to assume those books would be kind of out of date today?) or required experience with libraries that I didn't have and can't get. I hate getting stuck looking for the best resource to learn something instead of spending my time actually learning.

All I really want is someone to point me to a resource(website or ebook) that is aimed at already experienced java developers and will not only teach me some interesting useful java technology(anything that is useful, I dont know much outside of graphics libraries and game related things so I was thinking some database or web programming api's) but also give me a good perspective of it and leave me feeling confident that I could actually use what I learned on a practical application.

If my post makes you think I'm not yet experienced to be learning these things, which I doubted earlier today but am now starting to question, then what do you think is the next step for me? I just want to get better at java.

Thanks everyone

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: StackOverflow is aimed at answering specific programming questions. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). I would suggest you close this question and ask it at programmers.stackexchange.com, as @UmNyobe suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Register to the online courses at www.javapassion.com. It is cheap for the content and quality they offer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn is by doing. So I would recommend you to either start a private project which uses the technologies you want to learn or to find an open source project which uses them and contribute to that. The latter option has the advantage that you get feedback from other programmers, but the disadvantage that it leaves less room for experimentation.